# Heatmap on a network

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, links, tikz-graphdrawing

Is it possible to create the network heatmap using LaTeX as the one below?

[image: Network Heatmap]

The node size vary with the "Wait" field in the NodeData and link color changes according to the "Flow" fieled in the LinkData. I am aware of drawing the network using the tikz but not sure if such heatmap can be generated with TeX.

NodeData

```
nodeId  lat long    Wait
24  5   13  4426.0
20  5   32  0.0
21  5   22  0.0
22  13  22  0.0
23  13  13  0.0
1   51  5   2703.0
3   44  5   5421.0
2   51  32  1426.0
5   44  22  0.0
4   44  13  2703.0
7   38  42  3327.0
6   44  32  0.0
9   38  22  0.0
8   38  32  0.0
11  32  13  3588.0
10  32  22  0.0
13  5   5   2293.0
12  32  5   3564.0
15  19  22  0.0
14  19  13  2109.0
17  26  32  0.0
16  32  32  0.0
19  19  32  0.0
18  32  42  4420.0
```

LinkData

```
Id  fromNodeId  toNodeId    fromNodeLat fromNodeLong    toNodeLat   toNodeLong  Flow
0   5   6   44  22  44  32  0.0
0   18  20  32  42  5   32  505.0
0   21  22  5   22  13  22  0.0
0   2   1   51  32  51  5   240.0
0   12  3   32  5   44  5   350.0
0   14  15  19  13  19  22  0.0
0   9   10  38  22  32  22  0.0
0   21  20  5   22  5   32  0.0
0   9   5   38  22  44  22  0.0
0   15  14  19  22  19  13  0.0
0   16  8   32  32  38  32  0.0
0   11  10  32  13  32  22  0.0
0   17  10  26  32  32  22  0.0
0   12  11  32  5   32  13  1475.0
0   24  21  5   13  5   22  720.0
0   14  23  19  13  13  13  0.0
0   6   2   44  32  51  32  0.0
0   1   2   51  5   51  32  350.0
0   5   9   44  22  38  22  0.0
0   13  12  5   5   32  5   1105.0
0   10  11  32  22  32  13  0.0
0   1   3   51  5   44  5   590.0
0   4   11  44  13  32  13  0.0
0   3   12  44  5   32  5   295.0
0   6   8   44  32  38  32  0.0
0   22  23  13  22  13  13  0.0
0   7   8   38  42  38  32  0.0
0   22  15  13  22  19  22  0.0
0   19  15  19  32  19  22  0.0
0   5   4   44  22  44  13  0.0
0   3   4   44  5   44  13  855.0
0   11  12  32  13  32  5   1610.0
0   10  16  32  22  32  32  0.0
0   17  16  26  32  32  32  0.0
0   16  18  32  32  32  42  0.0
0   16  17  32  32  26  32  0.0
0   12  13  32  5   5   5   1175.0
0   24  23  5   13  13  13  0.0
0   23  14  13  13  19  13  0.0
0   23  22  13  13  13  22  0.0
0   22  20  13  22  5   32  0.0
0   20  19  5   32  19  32  0.0
0   8   16  38  32  32  32  0.0
0   11  4   32  13  44  13  0.0
0   8   6   38  32  44  32  0.0
0   20  21  5   32  5   22  0.0
0   10  17  32  22  26  32  0.0
0   16  10  32  32  32  22  0.0
0   18  16  32  42  32  32  0.0
0   7   18  38  42  32  42  1120.0
0   14  11  19  13  32  13  710.0
0   8   9   38  32  38  22  0.0
0   22  21  13  22  5   22  0.0
0   4   5   44  13  44  22  0.0
0   6   5   44  32  44  22  0.0
0   20  18  5   32  32  42  0.0
0   20  22  5   32  13  22  0.0
0   19  17  19  32  26  32  0.0
0   10  9   32  22  38  22  0.0
0   15  10  19  22  32  22  0.0
0   11  14  32  13  19  13  1410.0
0   15  19  19  22  19  32  0.0
0   3   1   44  5   51  5   700.0
0   23  24  13  13  5   13  0.0
0   18  7   32  42  38  42  983.076923077
0   13  24  5   5   5   13  850.0
0   21  24  5   22  5   13  0.0
0   2   6   51  32  44  32  0.0
0   24  13  5   13  5   5   770.0
0   9   8   38  22  38  32  0.0
0   19  20  19  32  5   32  0.0
0   4   3   44  13  44  5   910.0
0   15  22  19  22  13  22  0.0
0   8   7   38  32  38  42  0.0
0   17  19  26  32  19  32  0.0
0   10  15  32  22  19  22  0.0
```

Comment: TikZ is part of LaTeX. LaTeX is on top of TeX. It is not clear what you want as you write conflicting things. -also you need to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a `TikZ` solution where we read in the data from csv files using the `datatool` package, and we do some calculations using `xfp` package.  Hopefully you can make any needed adjustments on top of this...

### MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,datatool,xfp}
\definecolor{zero}{rgb}{1,1,.5}
\tikzset{
  Node/.style = {
    fill = gray,
    draw = none,
    circle,
    minimum width = \fpeval{1+sqrt(#1)/3},
  },
  Link/.style = {
    line width = 1mm,
    draw = {red!\fpeval{#1/20}!yellow!\fpeval{100*(#1>1)}!zero},
  },
  legend/.style = {
    anchor = west,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DTLloaddb{nodes}{NodeData.csv}
  \DTLforeach*{nodes}{\id=nodeId,\ny=lat,\nx=long,\nw=Wait}{%
    \node[Node={\nw}](\id) at (\nx/5,\ny/5){};
  }
  \DTLloaddb{links}{LinkData.csv}
  \DTLforeach*{links}{\nfr=fromNodeId,\nto=toNodeId,\flow=Flow}{%
    \draw[Link={\flow}] (\nfr) -- (\nto);
  }
  \node[legend] at (10,9.75) {Wait Time (pass-min)};
  \foreach \nw in {1,2,3,4,5}{
    \node[Node={\nw*1000}] at (10.5,10-\nw) {};
    \node[legend] at (11,10-\nw) {\nw000};
  }
  \node[legend] at (10,3.75) {Passenger Flow};
  \foreach \flow in {0,1,2,3,4}{
    \draw[Link={\flow*500}] (10.2,3-0.5*\flow) -- (10.8,3-0.5*\flow);
    \node[legend] at (11,3-0.5*\flow) {\fpeval{\flow*500}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: result]